# android map is moving slow after many overlays added

Tags: android, maps

My app has alot of overlays on the map, how do i keep the map from being so slow? Its like a 5 second delay when moving around on the map. Take a look at my code below on how i am adding people and can someone show me how to fix this so that its not so slow, I have about 80 overlays on my map and growing by the second.

```
ArrayList<String> lstotherslocation = MyGlobalInfomation.getOthersLocation();
              List<Overlay> mapOverlays = gMapView.getOverlays();
                Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.otherslocation);
                OthersLocationOverlay otherslocation = new OthersLocationOverlay(drawable,this);
                mapOverlays.clear();
                for(int i = 0; i < lstotherslocation.size();i++){
                    number = number + 1;
                      OthersPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(lstotherslocation.get(i).trim())),
                                                (int) (Double.parseDouble(lstotherslocation.get(i + 1).trim())));
                      OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(OthersPoint, "Title",
                      "test: " +  lstotherslocation.get(i+ 2) + "\n" +
                      "User: " + lstotherslocation.get(i+ 3) + "\n" +
                      "test: " + lstotherslocation.get(i+ 4) + "\n" +
                      "test: " +  lstotherslocation.get(i+ 5 ));
                    i = i + 5;
                    otherslocation.addOverlay(overlayitem);
                    mapOverlays.add(otherslocation);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why mapOverlays.add(otherslocation) is inside the for loop ?

Can you try with the following code :

```
OthersLocationOverlay otherslocation = new OthersLocationOverlay(drawable,this);
mapOverlays.clear();
mapOverlays.add(otherslocation);
for(int i = 0; i < lstotherslocation.size();i++){
    ....
    otherslocation.addOverlay(overlayitem);
}
```

I assume you want to have your 80 markers on the othersLocationOverlay ?

Comment: Yes i do, I am not sure what you are going at in your code compared to my code. My map has everthing it just very slow.

Comment: Isn't your mapOverlays.add(otherslocation) inside the for loop ? Put it out of the for loop and only include  otherslocation.addOverlay(overlayitem) in the loop

Comment: hi..have you fixed this problem,me too facing same thing,can you please guide me if you have solution.